# How to convert HTML file to PDF file in java

Tags: java, html, pdf

I have a html file and I want to convert it's content to pdf file 
I have tried XMLWorkerHelper and it's does not work for me.
for both function I got this error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.pdfelement.NoNewLineParagraph.set‌​MultipliedLeading(F)‌​V
Here there is the code I use (I tried two functions and in both of them I got problems with the XML get instance line, The variable HTML is the html file source code):

```
public void converttopdf(String html){  
    try{
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("PDFs/convert.pdf"));
    document.open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,new FileInputStream("HTMLs/test.html")); 
    document.close();
    System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
    }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void HtmlTOPdf(String html){
    try {
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("PDFs/convert.pdf"));
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
        document.open();
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
        document.close();
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: In order for someone to help you, you'll need to ensure you include specific details as opposed to very vague ones. Explain to us why "it does not work" for you. Do you get an error? If so, what is the error? Have you tried debugging it line by line? If so, what were the results? Tell us more details about why it won't work but keep it relevant.

Comment: for both function I got this error: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.pdfelement.NoNewLineParagraph.setMultipliedLeading(F)V

Comment: Ok well you should place that in your original question post so people don't have to flick through comments. Also, what does that error say to you? If you're struggling, paste it into google and see what others say about it. This is basic debugging and really good experience to do on your own! :D I could tell you what your problem is but you'll appreciate the solution more if you find it yourself. Happy hunting!

Comment: I appreciate that, But actually I'm still stuck with the same error.
 if you know what is the problem, please tell me what to do

Comment: What version of iText and XmlWorker are you using?

Comment: @Savlon's question is the important question to ask, most likely the versions differ while they must be identical.

Comment: I use xmlworker-5.5.6 , itextpdf-5.4.1

Comment: I downloaded identical versions, and the error disappeared, Now I have different problem with  XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance() that returns null instance